# Can I include an object carrying additional information in the exception?

Tags: c#, exception

I would like to define a custom exception, and I would like to know if I can include a class instead of a string as the message. The reason is that I would like to send extra information in a structure that can be more flexible.

Comment: "Throw a class instead a string"???Throw keyword always throws an exception which is a class.So, you are always throwing a class..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. Just create a class that inherits from Exception.

```
class YourException : Exception 
{
    public YourException(SpecialObject thethingYouWantIncluded) 
    {
        ExtraObject = thethingYouWantIncluded;
    }

    public SpecialObject ExtraObject { get; private set; }
}
```

then

```
throw new YourException(new SpecialObject());
```

and

```
catch (YourException ex) { /* do something with ex.ExtraObject here */ }
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can, sort of.

In C#, all exceptions are classes, they are instances of `System.Exception` or some class that is derived from that. If you want to make a custom exception, you just need to define a new class that inherits from `Exception`.

In this custom class, you can add whatever additional properties, fields, etc. that you want:

```
public class CustomException : Exception
{
    public Object CustomThing { get; set; }
}
```

When you catch such an exception into a variable of type `CustomException` you will have access to all of the custom properties you defined, just like any other class.

However, what you *can not* do is change the fact that `Exception.Message` is a string. Your custom message class will have a `Message` property and it will be a `string`, and you can't change it. You will need to define a custom string that includes all of the relevant information. You can override the `Message` property to return information from your custom properties, but it still needs to be a string:

```
public class CustomException : Exception
{
    public override string Message 
    { 
        get 
        {
            if (this.CustomThing == null) 
            {
                return base.Message;
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Format("Custom thing: {0}", this.CustomThing);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning: "However, what you can not do is change the fact that Exception.Message is a string."